# Citations within the bibliography (BibTeX)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

How can one cite a work within a reference entry using BibTeX? I have in mind something like:

> Smith, F. (2019). *The StackExchange guide to referencing*. City: Publisher.
>
> Jones, G. (2019). 'Citations within the bibliography' in (Smith 2019).

The case I'm concerned with is works within a collection (here a `@book` item containing an  `@incollection`), though I suppose the solution is more general (and of general interest).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Based on your description, I'd guess the entry type you're looking for is `@incollection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general feature responsible for this is BibTeX's `crossref` functionality. Not all styles implement this feature in the exact way you envision, but a great many do it in a way that comes close.

[`btxdoc`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf) explains `crossref` as follows (pp. 2-3)

> BibTeX has a new cross-referencing feature,
>   explained by an example.
>   Suppose you say `\cite{no-gnats}` in your document,
>   and suppose you have these two entries in your database file:
>
> ```
> @INPROCEEDINGS{no-gnats,
>   crossref = "gg-proceedings",
>   author = "Rocky Gneisser",
>   title = "No Gnats Are Taken for Granite",
>   pages = "133-139"}
> .  .  .
> @PROCEEDINGS{gg-proceedings,
>   editor = "Gerald Ford and Jimmy Carter",
>   title = "The Gnats and Gnus 1988 Proceedings",
>   booktitle = "The Gnats and Gnus 1988 Proceedings"}
> ```
>
> Two things happen.
>
> First, the special `crossref` field tells BibTeX
>   that the `no-gnats` entry should inherit
>   any fields it's missing from
>   the entry it cross references, `gg-proceedings`.
>   In this case it in inherits the two fields
>   `editor` and `booktitle`.
>   Note that, in the standard styles at least,
>   the `booktitle` field is irrelevant
>   for the `@PROCEEDINGS` entry type.
>   The `booktitle` field appears here
>   in the `gg-proceedings` entry
>   only so that the entries that cross reference it
>   may inherit the field.
>   No matter how many papers from this meeting exist in the database,
>   this `booktitle` field need only appear once.
>
> The second thing that happens:
>   BibTeX automatically puts the entry `gg-proceedings`
>   into the reference list if it's cross
>   referenced by two or more entries that you
>   `\cite` or `\nocite`,
>   even if you don't `\cite` or `\nocite`
>   the `gg-proceedings` entry itself.
>   So `gg-proceedings` will automatically appear
>   on the reference list if one other entry
>   besides `no-gnats` cross references it.
>
> To guarantee that this scheme works, however,
>   a cross-referenced entry must occur later in the database files
>   than every entry that cross-references it.
>   Thus, putting all cross-referenced entries at the end makes sense.
>   (Moreover, you may not reliably nest cross references;
>   that is, a cross-referenced entry may
>   not itself reliably cross reference an entry.
>   This is almost certainly not something you'd
>   want to do, though.)
>
> One final note:
>   This cross-referencing feature is completely unrelated
>   to the old BibTeX's cross referencing,
>   which is still allowed.
>   Thus, having a field like
>
> ```
>     note = "Jones \cite{jones-proof} improves the result"
> ```
>
> is not affected by the new feature.

Many styles then go on to simply issue as `\cite{<crossref parent>}` in the *`crossref` child* instead of repeating the inherited fields.

`apalike` comes quite close to what you seem to have in mind.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{apalike}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{westfahl:frontier,
  author       = {Westfahl, Gary},
  title        = {The True Frontier: {Confronting} and Avoiding
                  the Realities of Space in {American}
                  Science Fiction Films},
  pages        = {55-65},
  crossref     = {westfahl:space},
}
@book{westfahl:space,
  editor       = {Westfahl, Gary},
  title        = {Space and Beyond: {The} Frontier Theme in Science Fiction},
  year         = {2000},
  publisher    = {Greenwood},
  address      = {Westport, Conn.},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\cite{westfahl:frontier} \nocite{westfahl:space}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Westfahl, G., editor (2000a). Space and Beyond: The Frontier Theme in Science Fiction. Greenwood, Westport, Conn.//Westfahl, G. (2000b). The true frontier: Confronting and avoiding the realities of space in American science fiction films. In (Westfahl, 2000a), pages 55–65.]

Note that the *`crossref` parent* had to be `\nocite`d (or `\cite`d) explicitly here, because it only appears automatically in the bibliography without being `\cite`d (or `\nocite`d) if it is `crossref`'d at least twice. If  want the parents to appear even when they are only used once and  you can't be bothered to `\nocite` them, you can call BibTeX with the `-min-crossrefs` option and pass the value 1 to it

```
bibtex -min-crossrefs=1 <filename>
```

---

`biblatex` also has a `crossref` feature, but its inheritance rules are slightly more sophisticated (there is also an `xref` feature without inheritance). The standard styles don't `\cite` the parent entries, but my [`biblatex-ext` bundle](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) has the `citexref` feature that enables this.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear, citexref]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{westfahl:space,
  editor       = {Westfahl, Gary},
  title        = {Space and Beyond},
  subtitle     = {The Frontier Theme in Science Fiction},
  date         = {2000},
  publisher    = {Greenwood},
  address      = {Westport, Conn.},
}
@incollection{westfahl:frontier,
  author       = {Westfahl, Gary},
  title        = {The True Frontier},
  subtitle     = {Confronting and Avoiding
                  the Realities of Space in {American},
                  Science Fiction Films},
  pages        = {55-65},
  crossref     = {westfahl:space},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{westfahl:frontier} \nocite{westfahl:space}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Westfahl, Gary, ed. (2000a). Space and Beyond. The Frontier Theme in Science Fiction. Westport, Conn.: Greenwood.//— (2000b). ‘The True Frontier. Confronting and Avoiding the Realities of Space in American, Science Fiction Films’. In: Westfahl 2000a, pp. 55–65.]

As with BibTeX, the parent had to be `\nocite`d explicitly. `biblatex` also supports a *min-`crossref`* feature, it is called `mincrossrefs` and is a preamble option (so you don't need to worry about command line options). With

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear, citexref, mincrossrefs=1]{biblatex}
```

there would be no need to `\nocite` the `@collection` parent.

Comment: Thanks for the really helpful answer! I tend to use `apacite`, which seems to be having trouble with crossref (I haven't looked into the documentation for it yet!).

Comment: @MatthewMcClure Well, `apacite` implements the wishes of the APA. AFAIK APA style simply does not include these kinds of citations in the bibliography, they want the full entry data.

Comment: Yes, I just checked the documentation (replied to your answer in a rush – I was heading out).